# Using XML in Preprocessor Directives in c++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

In an article "[Using unmanaged C++ code in C# application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14180/Using-Unmanaged-C-Libraries-DLLs-in-NET-Applicatio?msg=2739665#xx2739665xx)" I found that a cpp source file is including header file as follows :

```
#include <span class="code-string">"CppWin32Dll.h"</span>
```

This is not a C++/CLI code.

Why it is being used like this? What does this imply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply `HTML-code`, that is in source by author/code-project mistake.